# How to reuse JSON data that may have changed?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, xmlhttprequest

I have a force directed graph and I want to be able to click buttons to change the JSON file used to present the graph.

I have a simplified version of what I have here in JSFiddle : Go to line 374 to go to the JS and skip the data

Now I havent got any buttons but I do call the function twice (at the bottom of the script) as if I am going back to the data I used first.

Now if you run it and look in the console it says: `it can not find weight of undefined.`

What i think is happening is somewhere the data is getting changed and I cant seem to find out how to fix this problem. I think its after line 419 where the changes to the data happen. This code is used to link the nodes properly.  This is a colleagues code so I'm just playing with it and I am unsure if I can link the nodes a better way, or even if this is where the changes are happening.

Any ideas ? All i wish to do is to change between two sets of data. So start on one, click a button, data changes, graph changes. Click the button again, goes back to the original data/graph.

Any help/pointers will be highly appreciated as this has been bugging me for a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are editing data on your JSON file so that when you return to that JSON file the second time, it has been altered so you cant use it in the same way as before

Comment: just figured that out myself, i have found a different way to link the nodes. appreciate the answer :)